# jquery ajax - second array push not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

i have this code that needs to populate an array that will be used on some diagramming tools. so there's a button that will show the results and a checkbox that enables the user to add another set of rows to the array. i use `.push()` for the array and it works. now, the problem is that the second push on my second ajax calls did not add the data to the array. here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetSubCategorySalesPerTerritory",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {        
        $.each(response.d, function (i, val) {            
            var values = new Array(val.From, val.To, val.Thickness);            
            rows.push(values); //this one works
        });        

        if ($('#chkPromotion').is(":checked")) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/AddPromotion",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {                    
                    $.each(data.d, function (i, val) {                        
                        var values = new Array(val.From, val.To, val.Thickness);                        
                        rows.push(values); //this one fails                        
                        alert("pushed");
                    });                    
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });            
            drawChart(rows);
        } else {            
            drawChart(rows);
        }        
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

i really don't know why it fails. what happens is that even if the condition is satisfied and the second ajax call succeeds, the contents of the array `rows` is still the first array push. what's the problem with the code?

Comment: Open the developer tool and check the response in netowrk section. from that you can make sure backend called and get the right data. It can be a cache issue. add cache: false, to ajax request and check.

Comment: i think it is called successfully. i've tried putting the concatenated values of the response on an alert box and it is showed. i also tried putting it in another array, but still not successful.

Comment: Is this is what you expected out put http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/25/

Comment: yes, that's the result i've been looking forward to.

Comment: Why do you have a POST request and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` when you aren't sending any data to the server?

Comment: i am sending data on the server, i just removed it for the purpose of posting it here. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result you are getting is actually expected because of async nature of ajax

you should call the method within the success callback of the second ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetSubCategorySalesPerTerritory",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {        
        $.each(response.d, function (i, val) {            
            var values = new Array(val.From, val.To, val.Thickness);            
            rows.push(values); //this one works
        });        

        if ($('#chkPromotion').is(":checked")) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/AddPromotion",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {                    
                    $.each(data.d, function (i, val) {                        
                        var values = new Array(val.From, val.To, val.Thickness);                        
                        rows.push(values);
                    }); 
                    drawChart(rows); // here
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });            
        } else {            
            drawChart(rows);
        }        
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: this actually answers my question. thank you! but i don't understand this 'async nature' of ajax though.

Comment: @DustineTheGreat hope this would give you the idea of async nature of ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call